# Is there a way to programatically determine the order in which functions are declared in a python module?

Tags: python

I'm working on a project where being able to discover the order of declaration of functions within a class would be quite useful.  Basically, I'd like to be able to guarantee that all functions within a class are executed in the order they are declared.

The end result is a web page in which the order of the output of the functions matches the order in which the functions are declared.  The class will inherit from a generic base class that defines it as a web page.  The web application will dynamically load the .py file.

Comment: By looking at the source code? What's your use case for needing to know this programmatically?

Comment: Why would you want to do this?

Comment: The goal is to automatically generate a dynamic web page from the class.  We'd like the order of the blocks to be used to determine the order of the resulting function outputs in the web page.

Comment: Is this Python 2 or 3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from types import MethodType, FunctionType
methodtypes = set((MethodType, FunctionType, classmethod, staticmethod))

def methods_in_order(cls):
    "Given a class or instance, return its methods in the order they were defined."
    methodnames = (n for n in dir(cls) if type(getattr(cls, n)) in methodtypes)
    return sorted((getattr(cls, n) for n in methodnames), 
                  key=lambda f: getattr(f, "__func__", f).func_code.co_firstlineno)
```

Usage:

```
class Foo(object):
    def a(): pass
    def b(): pass
    def c(): pass

print methods_in_order(Foo)
[<unbound method Foo.a>, <unbound method Foo.b>, <unbound method Foo.c>]
```

Also works on an instance:

```
print methods_in_order(Foo())
```

If any inherited methods were defined in a different source file, the ordering may not be consistent (since the sort relies upon each method's line number in its own source file). This could be rectified by manually walking the class's method resolution order. This would be a fair bit more complicated so I won't take a shot here.

Or if you want only the ones directly defined on the class, which seems like it might be useful for your described application, try:

```
from types import MethodType, FunctionType
methodtypes = set((MethodType, FunctionType, classmethod, staticmethod))

def methods_in_order(cls):
    "Given a class or instance, return its methods in the order they were defined."
    methodnames = (n for n in (cls.__dict__ if type(cls) is type else type(cls).__dict__)
                   if type(getattr(cls, n)) in methodtypes)
    return sorted((getattr(cls, n) for n in methodnames), 
                  key=lambda f: getattr(f, "__func__", f).func_code.co_firstlineno)
```

This assumes a new-style class.

Answer (score 4):

```
class Register(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self._funcs = []

    def __call__(self, func):
        self._funcs.append(func)
        return func


class MyClass(object):

     _register = Register()

     @_register
     def method(self, whatever):
         yadda()

     # etc
```

Comment: Does this really work? Clearly, I need to spend more time playing with decorators in Python!

Comment: This requires altering the class.

Comment: @JeremyWest:  I've not tried it but there's no reason it shouldn't work.

Comment: I think this should work, but when it was attempted I discovered that the register wasn't incrementing.  I wound up with the same value for each method within the class.